# Prevent const function being called for non-const object

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code contains a const and a non-const version of `operator()`. [It outputs](https://wandbox.org/permlink/KalQIcWgOufnLzrU)

> Non-const op, false
>   Const op, true
>   Const op, true
>   Const op, true

I.e. the const version is called if either the object of type `S` is const or if the submitted pointer is const - lines `// 2`, `// 3`, `// 4`. Now I want the code in line `// 2` to result in a compile time error, i.e. I want the const version to be callable only on const objects. Obviously a `static_assert` on `is_const_v<decltype(*this)>` will not work. Any other ideas?
I know, it is easy to cast a non-const variable to a const one. But that would make the *misuse* at least obvious.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct S
{
    void
    operator()( int * )
    {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha
            << "Non-const op, "
            << std::is_const_v<typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*this)> > << '\n';
    }
    void
    operator()( int const * ) const
    {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha
            << "Const op, "
            << std::is_const_v<typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*this)> > << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    S         s1;
    S const   s2;
    int       i1= 0;
    int const i2= 1;

    s1( &i1 ); // 1
    s1( &i2 ); // 2
    s2( &i1 ); // 3
    s2( &i2 ); // 4
}
```

**Edit**
The reasoning behind my question is as follows. I am storing the submitted pointer. This requires casting away constness of the submitted pointer. Now I want to prevent const data being modified erroneously.

Comment: It's legal to call a const function on a non const object so getting an error is going to be difficult.  Sounds like an XY problem though.  What are you trying to accomplish by making `2` and error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can explicitly delete the following version

```
void operator()( int const * ) = delete;
```

to disallow

```
s1( &i2 ); // 2
```

and

```
void operator()( int * ) const = delete;
```

to disallow

```
s2( &i1 ); // 3
```

Comment: Neat. I'm always surprised at how certain problems are so easily solved with `= delete;`. You wouldn't think it was *that* useful at first glance, and you don't usually think about it outside of the compiler-generated members.

Comment: Well nearly. I have to write `void operator()( int const * )  = delete;`. Your code disables line `// 3` Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let's see how it would work if it would be non member function, if we make `this` an explicit parameter (imaginary syntax):

```
void call(S* this, int*) {
    // Wha? we clearly know `S*` is not const
    std::is_const_v<typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*this)> >
}

void call(S const* this, int const*) {
    // same
    std::is_const_v<typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*this)> >
}
```

The soluton would be to delete functions with a different constness between parameters:

```
void call(S* this, int*) {}
void call(S const* this, int const*) {}
void call(S* this, int const*) = delete;
void call(S const* this, int*) = delete;
```

Now the same can be done with member function:

```
struct S {
    void operator()(int*) {}
    void operator()(int const*) const {}
    void operator()(int const*) = delete;
    void operator()(int*) const = delete;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the function from being called by deleting the version that takes a `const int*`. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    void foo(int*) {
        std::cout << "Calling foo(int*)\n"; 
    }
    void foo(int const*) const {
        std::cout << "Calling foo(int const*)\n"; 
    }
    void foo(int const*) = delete; 
};

int main() {
    S s1;
    S const s2;
    int i1;
    int const i2;

    s1.foo(&i1); // This compiles fine (both mutable)
    s2.foo(&i2); // This compiles fine too (both const)
    s2.foo(&i1); // This also compiles (s2 const, i1 mutable)

    s1.foo(&i2); // This fails as intended (s1 mutable, i2 const)
}
```